# Check if date is lower than 2010?

Tags: c#

I am trying to show in Grid employees that are hired before year 2010. How can i do that ? I have a class `Employee` with properties (FirstName, LastName, Id and EmploymentDate)

```
private List<Employee> _employees = new List<Employee>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employee employee1 = new Employee();

    employee1.FirstName = "Etrit";
    employee1.LastName = "Bujupi";
    employee1.Id = 1;
    employee1.EmploymentDay = DateTime.Today;
    _employees.Add(employee1);            

    Employee employee2 = new Employee();

    employee2.FirstName = "Urim";
    employee2.LastName = "Sadiu";
    employee2.Id = 2;
    employee2.EmploymentDay = new DateTime(2009, 1, 23);
    _employees.Add(employee2); 


    Employee employee3 = new Employee();

    employee3.FirstName = "Dardan";
    employee3.LastName = "Mexhuani";
    employee3.Id = 3;
    employee3.EmploymentDay = new DateTime(2007, 2, 7);
    _employees.Add(employee3);            

    Employee add = new Employee();
    if (_employees < System.DateTime.Now)
    {
        EmployeeGrid.DataSource = _employees;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
EmployeeGrid.DataSource = _employees.Where(e => e.EmploymentDay.Year < 2010).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
EmployeeGrid.DataSource = _employees.Where(x=> x.EmploymentDay.Year < 2010);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about changing this:

```
if (_employees < System.DateTime.Now)
{
    EmployeeGrid.DataSource = _employees;
}
```

to

```
 EmployeeGrid.DataSource = _employees.Where(e => e.EmploymentDay.Year < 2010).ToList();
```

It's likely that the `.ToList()` part at the end isn't needed, but I added it to be consistent with your actual data structure. I'd suggest trying it without `.ToList()` first, to see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Linq` to filter it:

```
employeeGrid.DataSource = _employees.Where(e => e.EmploymentDay.Year < 2010);
```

Of course it would be better not to add them in the first place checking the [`DateTime.Year`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        if (_employees < System.DateTime.Now)
        {
            EmployeeGrid.DataSource = _employees.Where(s => s.EmploymentDay.Year < 2010);
        }
```

You may need to add

```
        using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from e in _employees
            where e.EmploymentDay.Year < 2010
            select e;
```